# Curl error: Failed to connect to splynx.skytrendnetworks.com port 443: No route to host

Tags: php, api, postman, php-curl

My API is running perfectly in Postman but when I extract the code and try to run It locally or in my Server I get this Error `Curl error: Failed to connect to splynx.skytrendnetworks.com port 443: No route to host` below is my Code any Help will be appreciated

```
    <?php
     $url = 'https://splynx.skytrendnetworks.com/api/2.0/admin/customers/customer';
    
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://splynx.skytrendnetworks.com/api/2.0/admin/customers/customer',
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Splynx-EA (key=79 1349da848ee7b1b2faf2cbf8&nonce=28&signature=2A2E6A0AEC50D48C8DAEAvCA8862929681D3678D5B9)',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
      ),
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    }
    else
    {

    echo $response;
    
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
    }

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: You are sending POSTFIELDS data in a GET request ... or trying to

Comment: I'm Focusing on sending  a get request the code was generated by postman that's why it contains POSTFIELDS

Comment: the [endpoint](https://splynx.skytrendnetworks.com) doesn't seem to exist... that subdomain does not resolve afaik